# Plotting error bar in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix

I was trying to make a plot with proportions using matplotlib. When i try adding error bars (errors are `en` and `ew`), it gives me a `ValueError[Scalar | N, N*1, N*2 array-like]`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

pcd = np.array([0.25,0.56,0.66,0.75,0.88])
wpcd = np.array([0.40,0.53,0.80])
wf = np.array([0.33,0.50,0.60,0.80,0.88])
wf1 = np.array([0.50,0.60,0.80])
en = np.array([0.108,0.124,0.122,0.108,0.08])
ew = np.array([0.126,0.128,0.103])

plt.plot(wf,pcd,'o')
plt.errorbar(wf,pcd,yerr = en, fmt = 'o')
plt.plot(wf1,wpcd,'*')
plt.errorbar(wf1,wpcd,yerr = ew, fmt = 'o')
plt.show()
```

Comment: It would be helpful to show the code that generates the `ValueError`.

Comment: @unutbu updated the code giving value error

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using? (check `plt.matplotlib.__version__`).

Comment: the version is 2.0.2

Comment: You might want to upgrade your version of matplotlib. With version 2.2.0, the code you posted runs without error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
plt.errorbar(wf, pcd, yerr=en, xerr=en, fmt='o')
plt.show()
```